# post service is not calling throwing 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services

Hi friends I am using `Angularjs` and `rest-servies`  but when I am calling rest services from `service.js` file something is goning wrong and it is throwing  `400(bad request )`

### main.js

```
garantiesService.getTarifs($scope.recap.ageDirigeant,$scope.selectedCompany.zipcode)
 .success(function(){
    console.log('in  success');
  })
```

### service.js

```
healthApp.factory('garantiesService', ['$http', function($http) {
var service = {
  getTarifs: function(age,zipcode)
    {
        console.log("age : "+age);
        console.log("zipcode : "+zipcode);
        var directorHealthInsuranceInfo = {};

        directorHealthInsuranceInfo.age=age;
        directorHealthInsuranceInfo.department=zipcode;

        return $http.post('rest-service/quotes/health /director',directorHealthInsuranceInfo);

    }
};
return service;
```

### HealthInsuranceController.java

```
 @Controller
 public class HealthInsuranceQuoteResource {

 @RequestMapping("quotes/health/director")
 @ResponseBody
 public String quoteDirector(@RequestBody DirectorHealthInsuranceInfo info) {
   System.out.println("------HealthInsuranceQuoteResult------");
  return "hi";
```

}

### DirectorHealthInsuranceInfo.java

```
 @Value
public class DirectorHealthInsuranceInfo {
private String department;
private int age;
```

}

when I am sending the request it is throwing Bad Request 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is a space in the url you supplied to the http.post method. 
"rest-service/quotes/health /director"

I don't know if that is causing it.

But I also see that you POST your request to the service. Are you sure that your endpoint has been set up for POST requests?
I would recommend creating a basic endpoint that you call with a GET request, and no parameters. Just to root out the problem.

Comment: without parameter it is calling if I am passing the parameter then it is throwing 400 error.

Comment: try stringifying your data before sending it.
So JSON.stringify(directorHealthInsuranceInfo) in your post request.

Comment: There is definately something wrong with the definition of your endpoint. You haven't declared it as a POST method for starters..
A quick google gave me this http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/

Try it out :)